# covert byte stream to a image file in java

Tags: java, image, byte, java-ee-7

How to convert a byte stream to a image file and show the converted image to the application user.

The byte stream is return to my application by the client web service.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Please post that code/your efforts in order to get appropriate answers

Answer (score 0):

use this method..

```
public Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) 
{
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length); 
}
```